# MAX( ) WHERE - error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select statement (**working**)

```
 Select * FROM 
    (SELECT id, type, color, product,  
    SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity, 
    MAX(Date) AS LatestDate 
    FROM inventory 
    GROUP BY id, color, type) 
    AS alias 
    WHERE TotalQuantity > 0
```

I am trying to add a WHERE clause to the Max(Date) but I am not having any luck:

I thought I would just change it to: `MAX(Date) AS LatestDate WHERE stock = 1` But that does not work.

**Not Working:**

```
 Select * FROM 
    (SELECT id, type, color, product,  
    SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity, 
/* Problem Here */ MAX(Date) AS LatestDate WHERE stock = 1
    FROM inventory 
    GROUP BY id, color, type) 
    AS alias 
    WHERE TotalQuantity > 0
```

Comment: You need to describe your real intentions. The modified query makes no sense

Comment: The stock column has values of 1 or 0. 1 being incoming, 2 being outgoing. I want to get the latest date for only incoming stock being stock = 1. But I need the whole statement to SUM(Qauntity) for both stock incoming and outgoing stock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MAX(IF(stock = 1, Date, NULL)) AS LatestDate
```

It will find the max dates for `stock = 1` or `null` if there is no such rows

Comment: This is exactly the fix. I learnt something new too - Thanks for taken the time to understand the problem.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I was trying `MAX(Date) AS LatestDate IF stock = 1` - my php skills are severely lacking :( +1 for you!

Answer (score 1):

### Use the `WHERE` clause inside the Sub Select statement!

For your answer, please use this SQL:

```
Select * FROM 
    (SELECT id, type, color, product,  
    SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity, 
    MAX(Date) AS LatestDate 
    FROM inventory 
    GROUP BY id, color, type
    WHERE TotalQuantity > 0) 
    AS alias
```

Use the `WHERE` clause inside the Sub Select statement!

Comment: I need the WHERE clause to only apply to the Max(Date) and not the whole select statement.

Comment: Yea, it goes there only. Just give it a try. And it is for the sub-select. Not the whole select!

Comment: You were looking a the wrong WHERE ;) I am trying to add WHERE stock = 1 to the Max(Date)

Comment: Wait a sec... The way of `SELECT` is kinda wrong I guess. Check out the subselect syntax and write it again?

Comment: Okay see... I partially understood your problem. You can have a `WHERE` clause only for a `SELECT` statement. Use `IF` for your answer!